# Sample scraping Project Gutenberg using Beautiful Soup and requests

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to learn web scraping in Python using Beautiful Soup and requests. My program goes to the book page on Project Gutenberg with the given book number ([Example](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/1)). It then finds the link for the given format (text in this case) and then writes the contents of the book to a file on the hard disk.

How and what can I improve in this code?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def go_gutenberg(file_format,book_no):
       url = "https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/"
       r =requests.get(url+str(book_no))
       r_html  = r.text
       soup = BeautifulSoup(r_html,"html.parser")
       for file in soup.find_all('a',class_="link"):
         if file_format in file.text:
           get_book=file.get('href')
           g = requests.get("https:"+get_book)

           with open("C:\\Users\\syed\\Documents\\Gutenberg\\Book"+str(book_no)+".txt",'wb') as open_file:
               for chunk in g.iter_content(10000):
                    open_file.write(chunk)





def main():
go_gutenberg("Text",1000)

if __name__=="__main__":main()
```

And this is sample HTML of the book links:

> ```
> <a href="//www.gutenberg.org/files/53092/53092-0.txt"   
> type="text/plain;charset=utf-8" charset="utf-8" class="link" 
> title="Download">Plain Text UTF-8</a>
> ```

Comment: Just a heads-up, they have specific rules about automating these downloads.

Read more about automated downloading of the ebooks at: https://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/Gutenberg:Terms_of_Use

Which tells us, after you hit 100 ebooks, you will be automatically blocked. Not sure how many you want to scrape, but might be a important detail to keep in mind.

Comment: This is just for  learning  , I wont scrape that many . Thanks for the info ,  by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Easy stuff

There are a lot of stylistic issues (indentation, spacing between operators, etc.) that violate [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), you can use tools like [pylint](https://www.pylint.org/) to find what they are.

## Moving on

```
 r_html = r.text
```

Do you really need this? You don't save any characters (not that it is always about saving characters) and you use `r_html` once. I would just get rid of the line.

I would also say the same about:

```
url = "https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/"
```

Just get rid of it. Also, in this instance in particular I would get rid of it, because when I read it, I believe there might be a way to abstract it. "Maybe let the user change the `url`, somehow?") There isn't a particularly good way to "abstract" this `url` out in particular.

Furthermore, it is considered good practice to use format instead of the addition of strings so:

```
"https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/" + str(book_no)
```

Becomes:

```
"https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/%d" % book_no
```

This on the other hand:

```
"C:\\Users\\syed\\Documents\\Gutenberg\\Book"
```

Seems like it can be abstracted, what if the user wants to change the location? Maybe by default use this location, but allow the user to change it. Create a *default argument* to `"C:\\Users\\syed\\Documents\\Gutenberg\\Book"` but give the user the option to specify it.

Same with:

```
for chunk in g.iter_content(10000):
```

What is `10000`? Maybe make a default argument for this with the value of `10000` and the name of (possibly) `chunk_size`?